# Switching careers from Web Development to Front End Developer

Tags: software-industry, career-switch

In 2011 I got my first (and last) Web Developer job, which I kept for around 3 years. During this time I was going through some personal stuff, that made me very depressed and the fact that web development is that sort of job that you take home with you wasn't helping, I joined as a trainee, and after six months was promoted to Developer, and was involved in a project that would occupied my time completely for the next year and a half.

Socially I became very isolated and I wasn't getting along with most of my colleges at work. I just didn't fit in. I told my boss that I wanted to quit, but I eventually decided to stay on, and I was taken off the project. But unfortunately things didn't get better for me. I realized that I hated my job, I was tired of coding. I handed in my resignation, and left for good.

Initially I wanted to take a year off and just figure out what I wanted to do. Which is what I did. I started freelancing that year, and at this moment, it's something that is slowly picking up speed. I'm constantly working now. I've started to take on design jobs, even though I'm not that good at it, I am getting better.  But my year off is up now, and I need to make a decision. So, my question is, coming from being a developer, what more skills should I learn to become a front end developer.

My goal is to finally remove myself from development completely and just do design, but I feel like right now I am not good enough in that, and I already have the skills I need for front end development. I know, CSS,Jquery a certain amount of mootools(though I don't think anyone will be using this now), what other skills should I learn, before starting to apply for jobs?

I'm a worried about going into working for a company again as well.

Also, what has your experience been switching jobs?

Comment: Why don't you do Graphic Design?

Comment: "web development is that sort of job that you take home with you"  - I would suggest you have been working for the wrong company.

Comment: I would say that if you are constantly working as a freelancer, that your "year off" ended some time ago. Are you paying the bills with your freelancing? If so, why rush into abandoning it for a salaried gig?

Answer (score 2):

Learn responsive design.  I'd also check out twitter's bootstrap.  You may also want to check out other JavaScript frameworks such as Angular, though I suspect that that may be more coding than you're interested in.  Most importantly, put together a portfolio, and make a portfolio website to show it off.  Other than the portfolio part, I'd start applying to jobs now, and learning as you apply.